# Fix pinhole leak on shower mixing valve

Tags: shower, valve, bathroom-fixtures, copper-tubing, soldering

I tried removing the bonnet nut from my old Delta style shower ball valve. I tried [blow torching](https://youtu.be/DoTW0OeVBdM) a bit, but in the end used a plumber's wrench and ended up twisting the thin copper pipes from the rough in pipe.

In the process I created 3 pinholes that [shoots water upwards](https://youtu.be/qzpIhfYl-xA) from in between the brass rough in valve and copper tubes that goes to the hot side of the ball valve mixer. I tried using the blowtorch, but it is very difficult getting the flame to stay on and heating enough for the solder to melt onto the pipe. In the video, I couldn't adjust the flame and hold the camera at the same time.

I've tried using some [epoxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFcuo.jpg) ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BoZZ.jpg)), but I'm sure that won't hold.

Is there any other way I can spot weld or seal these pinholes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUvVw.jpg

[image: pin hole leak]

Comment: It's hard to tell from your pictures/description exactly what we are looking at. Did you try to remove the outer decorative plate from your shower valve? It may be best to cut the twisted, pin-holed pipe and fittings (and old valve?)out and redo all. Having said that, there is a product called stretch and seal tape in hardware store plumbing dept. that could be used for this purpose...but how well it would hold and for how long in this case is speculative and not s good long-term solution.

Comment: @DAS I'm not sure you looked at the photos since the decorative plate is removed in all of them. I uploaded to [YouTube](https://youtu.be/qzpIhfYl-xA) the very short video of the leak. The leak is between the rough in valve and the very thin copper tubes that comes from the hot side to the valve mixing side. If you look closely it is spraying upwards.

Comment: Rick, since you damaged the pipe you have 2 choices replace with plastic plumbing or replace with copper plumbing. I do a lot of copper both for plumbing and hvac , even with oxy acetylene and silver solder trying to patch pipes is really only a bandaid. I have found both epoxy and attempts to fix pin holes on rentals and flips, how did I find them? From the leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You have damaged the valve and it will need to be replaced.

Judging from the photos the "bonnet nut" **Is not a nut and is not designed to be removable by turning it with a wrench**. It has three copper pipes pressed or soldered into the back side so it can not be turned of as if it was one pipe with a threaded connection.

I believe any hack "**repair**" you do will not be sufficient and will fail in time and since it will be out of sight in a wall you will **not know if it fails** until it causes a very large drain in you bank account. **I.E.** Damage that will require significant work to replace and mitigate water damage and possible mold.